# Navigation bar becomes transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller, presentviewcontroller

navigation bar transparent while picking a video from image picker controller

[image]

I'm trying to pick a video using image picker controller. while picking a video, previous screen title is visible or navigation bar is transparent.
This is only happening on iPad, not on iPhone. My code is as given,

```
    imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: have you customised the appearance of `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: Actually no, I'm just presenting imagepickercontroller on a view controller. And this happens after picking video from gallery and preview screen of video.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is value in `UINavigationBar`'s `Appearance` you can remove it by putting this line before you `present` your `UIPickerView`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = nil
```

if you want to put the value back after user picked image/video you can do it in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` function `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` and also in `imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make navigation bar transparent while scrolling you need to set colour when you pickerview 1) appears 2) is scrolling 3) and has selected an item.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24495938/2105158) is the link. I hope that answers you question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your questions